# SP Online - Can you create a webpart with C# CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I want to create custom WebPArt for SharePoint Online. Can you realize this with C# CSOM ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about Classic web parts like we've had since SharePoint 2007, the answer is no. To create those types of web parts you need to write Server Object Model code which cannot be deployed to SharePoint Online.

You have two options when it comes to building custom web parts in SharePoint Online. You can use HTML and JavaScript with the Content Editor or Script Editor web part or you can build a Client-Side Web Part with the SharePoint Framework (which is currently still in preview).